# Apache rewrite : how avoid to display url parameter when the url final slash is omitted?

Tags: url-rewriting, apache2.4

In my .htacess of my domain, I must point subdomain to the 1rst GET parameter of the domain. The subdomain represents the language (for example en., fr, etc...).
In order to achieve this aim, here the rewrite code in the .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=%1 [NC,L]
```

I create a directory named `test`. This directory contains just index.html file.

So when you type in the url bar of a browser `en.example.com/test/`, 
the rewrite code works.

But if you type `en.example.com/test` without the final slash, it redirects to `en.example.com/test/?lang=en` => it's a problem.

So have you an idea to correct that ?

Thank you in advance, cordially.

Comment: See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) at 'trailing slash problem'. It's for Apache 2.0 but still applies for 2.4.

Comment: Thank you, but I try it in my code :
 

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=%1 [NC]

RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -d

RewriteRule    ^(.+[^/])$           $1/  [R]`

=> it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll want to place that new rule *before* the one you already have.

Comment: You want to mean that ? : 

`RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -d

RewriteRule    ^(.+[^/])$           $1/  [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=%1 [NC,L]`

=> it doesn't work again

Comment: With your original rules, if you enter `en.example.com/test/` (with the slash), does it redirect to `en.example.com/test/?lang=en` too?

Comment: No, with my original rules (in my question post), `en.example.com/test/` doesn't redirect to `en.example.com/test/?lang=en` because it works. But when I omitted the last slash, it redirects to `en.example.com/test/?lang=en` even if the `test` directory exists.

Comment: That's pretty strange. It looks like your rule is intended to redirect `xx.example.com/whatever` to `xx.example.com/whatever?lang=xx` in all cases. Having Apache fix missing trailing slashes on directories like it does seems desirable.  You say that the rewrite code works for `en.example.com/test/`, but no rewriting is being done?
Also, I don't understand why you want to duplicate the language in the subdomain to a GET parameter - this defeats having subdomains. Can't you simply get the language from the domain name?

Comment: "You say that the rewrite code works for en.example.com/test/, but no rewriting is being done?"
=> the rewriting is done, because in the `/test/index.html` file, I put `<?php echo $_GET["lang"];?>`, so when I type `en.example.com/test/`, the page displays `en` (the GET["lang"] value) => that proves that the rewriting is done. 

But when I omit the last slash by typing `en.example.com/test`, it redirects to `en.example.com/test/lang?=en` => it's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying `xx.example.com/test/`, an internal redirect
occurs to `xx.example.com/test/?lang=xx`. The client never sees the `?lang=xx`.

However, when specifying `xx.example.com/test`, where `test` is a directory,
`mod_dir` steps in and rewrites the URL to `xx.example.com/test/`, but in
such a way that the rewrite rule for the `?lang=xx` redirect becomes public,
having the client see `xx.example.com/test/?lang=xx` as the URL - which is unwanted.

In order to keep the '?lang=' redirect local (hidden from the client)
place this in the .htaccess, BEFORE the original rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}         -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$                  $1/ [R,L]
```

The condition checks whether the requested filename is a directory,
and the rule forces a client-side redirect `[R]`, so that a client requesting `xx.example.com/test` will be redirected to `xx.example.com/test/`.

The key however is the `[L]`, which makes this rule the Last, preventing the following rules from executing. Without this `L` flag, the entire redirect from `xx.example.com/test` to `xx.example.com/test/?lang=xx` becomes public.

After the client is forcefully redirected to the proper URL with a terminating `/`, the rewrite rules doing the internal redirect adding the `lang` GET parameter are executed as normal.

Here's the entire .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$              $1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}            ^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                  $1?lang=%1 [NC,L]
```

There is however another way to achieve this without using Apache config and internal redirect, and that is to examine `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`:

```
<?php
list( $lang ) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['SERVER_NAME'] );
```

Comment: I want to click +1.000.000, but the button is up to 1. Thank you very (and very) much ! The `L` flag is necessary and it works perfectly thanks to you. But, your php trick is the genius and best way !!!